# Update iframe contents (hide some HTML elements)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I have an **Angular** project, and I need to render an **iframe** inside one of pages.
This **iframe** renders another web tool that I need to use inside my project but with limited usage as there is many buttons and icons I don't need. So I need the iframe to just render the required icons. What I think is about `display: none;` the unneeded elements.

I found some suggestions about updating iframe contents using jQuery, but don't work with me.

**Note**: The web tool is installed locally but I don't need to edit its original code.

Comment: you can pass to iframe some message with postMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). In the iframe you can interecept that message and hide some elements; otherwise, during startup,  you can pass to iframe some params on url with querystring

Comment: @Max But in this case I have to change the web tool (iframe source) code, right?

Comment: yes, if you want to react to the message

Comment: As I mentioned I don't need to update the original source code as I clone and install the tool locally and I don't need to do any manual additions in it.

Comment: Can you modify the iframe contents using iFrame.contentWindow?

Comment: @user1599011 Permission denied to access because of cross-origin